# Agora Cloud Recording Composite Host (person that requested) not recorded in Web

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng, agora, agora-implementation, agora-cloud-recording

`https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/{{APPID}}/cloud_recording/resourceid/{{resourceId}}/mode/{{mode-type}}/start`

When I try to use Cloud Recording Composite with the official Agora API documentation in Postman, I do get the recordings in MP4 format fine, all users in the call are present except for the person who requested (uid passed in the request). How do I include the hosts audio and video streams to the MP4 composite recording?

(In this example all users present are using the web version)

```
{
    "cname":"yXazJoR5lR7LXaay9g4l",
    "uid": "123",// Person with this UID will not be included in the composite recording.
    "clientRequest": {
        "token": "",
        "recordingConfig": {
            "channelType": 0,
            "streamTypes": 2,
            "audioProfile": 1,
            "videoStreamType": 0,
            "maxIdleTime": 120,
            "transcodingConfig": {
                "width": 1920,
                "height": 1080,
                "fps": 30,
                "bitrate": 3150,
                "maxResolutionUid": "123",
                "mixedVideoLayout": 0
            },
            "subscribeUidGroup": 1
        },
        "recordingFileConfig": {
            "avFileType": ["hls","mp4"]
        },
        "storageConfig": {
            "vendor": 6,
            "region": 6,
            "bucket": "x",
            "accessKey": "x",
            "secretKey": "x"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried specifying subscribeVideoUids and subscribeAudioUids but that did not help, the host was still not present in the agora composite recording MP4.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using a unique, random user UID in the `uid` field. Make sure to specify `subscribeVideoUids` and `subscribeAudioUids`

[Documentation](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/get-started/getstarted)

> The recording service is equivalent to a non-streaming client in the
> channel. The uidparameter in the request body is used to identify the
> recording service and cannot be the same as any existing user ID in
> the channel. For example, if there are two users already in the
> channel and their user IDs are 123 and 456, the uid cannot be "123" or
> "456".